# Database 1...n relation with several owner tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I want to create a database scheme and don't really know a solution for the following scenario:
I have users, teams and projects. I want to enable to create projects as a user, but also as a team. What I thought of, was to include two foreign keys in the projects table. One for 'userId' and one for 'teamId'. But in this case for each entitiy either userId or teamId would be null.
Is this a good solution or is there a better possibility to solve that?

Comment: Not a programming question. Please take a look at this: http://databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_getting_started_with_db_design/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constraint that would force `userId != null OR teamId != null`.

Alternatively, you can require each project to have a non null foreign key `userId` (some user in the team had to actively create the project, right?), and then create an `associatedTeam` foreign key (which can be optional).